# expression must have integral or enum type about an easy function

Tags: c++

I want to know why the line of float tc1_2cif_c have many errors about expression must have integral or enum type

```
float age;
float cfd0;
float value;
float k0;
float k11;
float kr1;
float kr2;
float comfd0;
float kr5;
float kr6;
float kr7;
float cr1;
float cr2;    
value = 0.0f;
square=0.0f;

float tc1_2cif_c=-((cfd0*(exp((-k0/2. - kr1/2. - kr2/2. - kr5/2. - sqrt((k0 + kr1 + kr2 + kr5)^2. - 4.*(k0*kr2 + k0*kr5 + kr1*kr5))/2.)*t) - exp((-k0/2. - kr1/2. - kr2/2. - kr5/2. + sqrt((k0 + kr1 + kr2 + kr5)^2. - 4.*(k0*kr2 + k0*kr5 + kr1*kr5))/2.)*t))*kr1)/sqrt((k0 + kr1 + kr2 + kr5)^2. - 4.*(k0*kr2 + k0*kr5 + kr1*kr5)));

cr1= tc1_2cif_c;


cr2= tc2_2cif_c;



IF=a1*exp(l1*t)+a2*exp(l2*t);
square=(   mv_r -( cr1+cr2+vb*IF)  );



value += 0.5*(square*square);
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this subexpression, for example:

```
(k0 + kr1 + kr2 + kr5)^2
```

The operator `^` doesn't do what you think it does. It is not "exponent" (or "power") operator. Also, it does **not** apply on floating-point numbers. It is a bitwise XOR operator, applies only on integral types (that includes enum as well!).

Use [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function instead:

```
std::pow(k0 + kr1 + kr2 + kr5, 2)
```